# How can a generate an array of 5 random, single digit (0-9) integers?

Tags: java, arrays, string, random, java.util.scanner

I am developing a game that gets the user to crack a vault code.

```
int [] vault = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

I currently just have per-determined values for the vault code (above) but I think it would be best if they changed with each play-through of the game.

I have seen the math.random method but I'm unsure how to make it only display integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with java 8 you can use the random Object's method [ints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-):

```
Random r = new Random();
long l = 10;
int lowBound =1;
int highBound =100;
int[] myArray = r.ints(l, lowBound, highBound).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
import java.util.Random;

Random rand = new Random();

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
value[i] = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;  //5 will be maximum and 1 will be minimum
}

//value now has 5 ints generated randomnly.
```